# Grails domain mapping property name to column identified as id but has different name than property

Tags: hibernate, grails, mapping, grails-orm

I have seen several questions that seem to be very close to this subject but doesn't seen to answer totally. So here it is. I have a legacy table that will not be changed. The relevant schema is that there is a table with a column called LICNUM. This column must be used as the primary key. However I would like to put descriptive property names in my domain classes. So I would like to map the property name licenseNumber to that column.

Now I have read the grails documentation and from what I understand it should be accomplished with this mapping:

```
id name:'licenseNumber' ,column:'LICNUM', generator:'assigned'
```

However when I use this mapping hibernate is still looking for  license_number as a column in the database. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something below successfully.  Are you doing this in the mapping closure?

```
static mapping = {
    id column:'LICNUM'
}
```

See examples in documentation:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html